# Can I trim a preg_replace match in the same line?

Tags: php, regex

I am looking into a way to clean a generated class attribute using regular expressions.

Having this html

```
<div class=" class1 class2 ">
```

and using this preg

```
$string = preg_replace('/class=["\'](?P<class>[^"\'<>]+)["\']/i', 'class="$1"', $string);
```

How do I tell php to trim the trailing spaces around $1? ($1 is basically whats inside class)

Are there other ways to detect and replace end spaces?

Thank you

**Edited:** basically I am tring to do this

'class="'.trim($1).'"'

but $1 is not available as variable. I already tried $$1 and ${$1}. Maybe there is some other syntax to do this.

Comment: $string = preg_replace(pattern, replace, trim($string)); This could be done in your regex pattern but I'm being lazy today! I'm not really good at regex :-)

Comment: Not sure how to place trim inside this 'class="$1"'. Currently the preg matches the class and replaces it whit the same value which is $1. But how do I trim $1 only

Comment: What is $1? You can't name a variable 1 in PHP. or 2, or 3... If you mean that as a literal string, do trim('class=$1'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slightly modified regex to NOT capture spaces on either side in `$1`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/class=["\']\s*(?P<class>[^"\'<>]+?)\s*["\']/i', 'class="$1"', 
          '<div class=" class1 class2 ">') );


var_dump( $string );
string(27) "<div class="class1 class2">"
```

Answer (score 0):

***How do I tell php to trim the trailing spaces around $1?***

You can do rtrim and ltrim to trim down starting and trailing spaces and keep the middle once, which are important.

```
$string = '<div class=" class1 class2 ">';
$string = preg_replace('/class=["\'](?P<class>[^"\'<>]+)["\']/i', '$1', $string);
$string = rtrim($string);  
$string = ltrim($string);
$string = 'class="'.$string.'"';
```

Comment: $string is basically a full html page so I am not sure this works

Comment: oh I see, in that case anubhava's solution is just perfect.